# How to remove focus border for Ant design Tabs component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I use ant design in react project.

This is tabs from offsite

[image]

When I click on tab content the frame appears around the content

[image]

How can I remove this border?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **outline** styles

```css
outline: none;
```

Usage sample:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
  <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1" style={{outline: 'none'}}>
...
```

[image]